# How to set the Test Phase field in Team Foundation Server

Tags: tfs

I am looking for a way to track the testing status of user stories in TFS. I noticed a field named Test Phase as an option in the search query, but I don't see how to edit that field. How do I edit the Test Phase of a user story?

Comment: What version of TFS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot see Test Phase as a field on any Process Templates I have downloaded (that's not to say it's not there), so my advice might not be accurate.

You could try and [customise the TFS process template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243782.aspx) to show this "Test Phase" field on the User Story - depending on what it's purpose is. You can experiment with Microsoft Excel by creating a query and adding that as a Column.

Another option, depending on what you need to track. If it is just to see what needs testing, then you can Customise the Kanban lanes on the Backlog Board. Esteban has an excellent article [here](http://www.almguide.com/2013/04/tfs-2012-update-2-kanban-board/) describing the process.